# WP Plugin Developers - Accessing my wordpress site

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I bought and installed a premium plugin from a major plugin developer. I don't want to expose the company here **IF** what I just experienced is in fact legal for them to do.

I'm hoping a WP Plugin Developer can help me understand this.

As I said, I purchased a license for a plugin from a very well known and established wordpress plugin developer / company. I installed it and had a very simple issue, I then went to their site which they have 24/7 chat support.

I asked about a particular settings page of the plugin being blank. They chat support person initially said it was because of a conflict with another plugin. I said, "No, I doubt it because I only have the latest WP, the latest Elementor Pro and your plugin installed. No other plugins or custom code." I had installed it on production site (with numerous other plugins) and then I installed it on dev.same-site just to confirm it wasn't another plugin conflict.

After about 2 mins, she said, **"Elementor is compatible I can see you have a lot of third-party plugins on your dashboard"**.

She was referring to the production site. I was thrown back because now I'm wondering how is she able to tell me I have alot of other 3rd party plugins?? (which I do)

I know some plugins can "call home", but how is she able to "see" that I have alot of plugins?
Is this even legal?

Comment: Sorry to hear, but I'm afraid this is not the right place for a question like this. For law questions best consult a lawyer (if you want to stick with SE, try [Law StackExchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/)). Probably depends a lot on jurisdiction and what exactly has happened (aka your colleague sent them a account or something). To me personally this sounds like a big red flag, as it seems like "calling home" that you speak of and should not take place.

Answer (score 2):

When you install a plugin (or realy any software except maybe on IOS and android in which you have to additionaly grunt permissions) you basically give the author of the plugin an unlimited access to whatever you can do on your machine, therefor trust in the developer is something that just can't be emphesized enough.

If you trust the developer in general there is no reason to be alarmed that he can find out whatever information that is accessable to you, like which plugins are installed.

I would not have known anything specific about the plugin even if you specified its name, but I can guess that information like which plugins you have installed is sent to their server with a license validation request or similar. It might even be written somewere in the license agreement.

But best way forward, instead of imagening things, is to just ask them.